# Are linters capable of catching typos in function names?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm using [eslint](http://eslint.org/).  I checked the [config](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring) and do not see any case convention options.

I ran into a case:

`myString.startswith('blah');`

Where it should be

`myString.startsWith('blah');`

The accidental lowercase `'w'` is a bit of a booger to catch.  This results in a runtime error.  I'm using Reactjs (doubt it matters).

Is it possible and practical to enable case sensitivity linting of function calls?

Comment: For knowing what methods exist on an object and which don't, you usually need a typing system not a linter.

Comment: @Bergi - I'm not looking to answer the question of whether a function exists on an object.  Rather, does the function follow the JS convention of using camelCase.

Comment: You'd need to use a word list for that. Yes, it certainly would be possible (and work similar to a typical spell checker), but it doesn't come with eslint. You can write your own plugin for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESLint will not be your friend here.

This is where tests come into play to test that your code does what you *think* it should be doing.